# Missing Method when importing

Tags: excel, vb.net, import, missing-data, closedxml

```
Imports ClosedXML.Excel 

Sub import()

    'Open the Excel file using ClosedXML.
    Using workBook As New XLWorkbook(file_pr)
        'Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
        Dim workSheet As IXLWorksheet = workBook.Worksheet(1)

        'Create a New DataTable.
        Dim dt As New DataTable()

        'Loop through the Worksheet rows.
        Dim firstRow As Boolean = True
        For Each row As IXLRow In workSheet.Rows()
            'Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
            If firstRow Then
                For Each cell As IXLCell In row.Cells()
                    dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString())
                Next
                firstRow = False
            Else
                'Add rows to DataTable.
                dt.Rows.Add()
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                For Each cell As IXLCell In row.Cells()
                    dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = cell.Value
                    i += 1
                Next

            End If
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

When I'm importing excel using this query, appear error.

> 'Method not found:'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElementList
> DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement.get_ChildElements()'.'.

Please help me to solve it

Comment: 1) Does the error happen on the `Using workBook As New XLWorkbook(file_pr)` line? 2) Does the error happen with a different Excel file?

Comment: yes, the error was happen on the Using workBook As New XLWorkbook(file_pr). Im using excel extension .xlsx

Comment: Is the project using the latest version of ClosedXML? Have you tried removing ClosedXML and adding it again? You could also try to [clean the solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/building-and-cleaning-projects-and-solutions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#to-build-rebuild-or-clean-an-entire-solution) and then build it again.

Comment: i'm already try removing ClosedXML and adding again also try to clean and build again, but this not work to the error, the error appear same again

Comment: I think this is probably related to https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/2220

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. ClosedXML doesn't fully support the new DocumentFormat.OpenXML v3.0.0 release, which introduced some breaking changes.

I fixed it by downgrading the version of the DocumentFormat.OpenXML package to 2.20.0.

[Related GitHub issue](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/2220)

Comment: thank you, im try your plan and this successfuly to work import